# In Ruby, how does puts _|_ work?

Tags: ruby, irb, puts

I am confused with how `puts _|_` works in Ruby.  If you type in a variable and then call that statement

```
3
puts _|_
```

you get the name of the variable followed by nil

```
 3
 => nil
```

However, if you type it again, you get false

```
puts _|_
=> false
```

It doesn't seem like one of those Perl-like variables that begin with a dollar sign.

What in the world does this weird symbol mean and how does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underscore in a console (IRB or pry) stands for the result of the previous command. So

```
3
=> 3
puts _|_
3
=> nil
```

Here the above `puts` statement becomes equivalent to

```
puts 3 <bit-wise or> 3
```

which `puts 3|3` equals `puts 3`.

Since `puts` returns `nil`, when you repeat the `puts _|_` it becomes

```
puts nil|nil
```

... which is `puts false`.

Answer (score 3):

`_` is a ruby special variable, it is used to get the result of the previous expression.

```
irb(main):030:0> 3
=> 3
irb(main):031:0> _
=> 3
irb(main):032:0> _.to_s
=> "3"
irb(main):033:0> _
=> "3"
```

A ruby variable whose name begins with a lowercase letter (a-z) or underscore (_) is a local variable or method invocation. Uninitialized instance variables have a value of nil.

```
irb(main):001:0> _
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> _ | _
=> false
irb(main):003:0> nil | nil
=> false
```

Answer (score 3):

In ruby `_` is a valid identifier.

In `IRB` `_` contains the value of the last expression.

```
2.1.5 :001 > 100
 => 100
2.1.5 :002 > _
 => 100
```

Answer (score 0):

`_` is a ruby special variable, this variable stores out put of the previous expression/command, so when you do:

```
1.9.3-p0 :043 > 3
 => 3
```

'_' contains the value 3, because return value of previous expression is 3. When you use puts as below:

```
1.9.3-p0 :045 > puts _|_
3
 => nil
```

its return value is nil.Next time when you execute the *|* as below:

```
1.9.3-p0 :049 > _|_
 => false
```

it returns false because it is same as below expression:

```
1.9.3-p0 :050 > nil|nil
 => false
```

that is why puts *|* returns false.